# Do I need to release NSNumbers added to a NSDictionary myself?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm creating an NSDictionary which maps objects to integers, and because NSDictionaries don't handle anything but objects I have to wrap each integer in an NSNumber object with [NSNumber numberWithInt:30] or what have you. What I'm not clear about is whether or not I need to release all of those NSNumber objects I'm creating. I'm not actually alloc'ing the space for them, so they must be in the autorelease pool, but can I be sure that the NSDictionary object is retaining and releasing them properly? Let's say I'm setting

```
NSDictionary * myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: objectOne, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 30], nil];
```

and I'm properly releasing the NSDictionary when I'm done with it (since I *am* alloc'ing the space for that within my own code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope the NSNumber objects are autoreleased.

Adding them to an NSDictionary will cause a retain message to be send to each NSNumber object you add.

According to the Memory Management Rules you don't own these objects - NSDictionary does that somehow - and thus you are not responsible releasing them, the NSDictionary object will do that.

But you own the NSDictionary created with alloc & initWithObjectsAndKeys:. Therefore you need to take care about managing memory of the myDict object.

Comment: numberWithInt is a convenience method (i.e. it's called on the class). Therefore since you didn't call a method called initXXX, according to memory management rules the object is returned autoreleased.

Comment: correct. But you need to check if it is necessary to release it manually or use the autorelease mechanism - the latter applies to this case

Answer (score 1):

No. You're doing fine.

You are adding an autoreleased NSNumber to a dictionary. The dictionary will retain the NSNumber, so when it eventually autoreleases, it will still be valid.

However just a couple of points so you don't get careless. You realise that the NSNumber is the key and objectOne is the value that is being stored in the dictionary? This is okay, because NSNumber conforms to the NSCopying protocol, which is a requirement for objects that are used as keys.

Comment: Ah, you're right, NSDictionary initialized that way takes in object pairs Value-Key-Value-Key, not Key-Value-Key-Value. Although that doesn't matter for my purposes. I'm still not clear on exactly *how* I know that the NSDictionary will retain the autoreleased objects that go into is. Is this just something that the object has to be designed to do - meaning I have to check the documentation for any object that might possibly contain another object? Or is there some other generalization I can use to tell what to do?

Comment: All collections retain their objects. Think about how you would do it. Think of it like properties - you write a custom class with properties, you set these properties to objects, and your class retains its properties. This shows up all over iOS. Your application's main window retains it's view controllers, views retain their subviews, when you show a modal view controller, that is retained as well. Basically; iOS retains anything that it needs to keep a hold of, whether objects in a collection, or view controllers.

Comment: What I mean to say is - "You'll get used to it"